# regex filename pattern match

Tags: java, regex

I am using the below regex expression :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)?(\\..*)?");

while(new File(fileName).exists())
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
    if(m.matches()) { //group 1 is the prefix, group 2 is the number, group 3 is the suffix
        fileName = m.group(1) + (m.group(2) == null ? "_copy" + 1 : (Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)) + 1)) + (m.group(3)==null ? "" : m.group(3));
    }
}
```

This works fine for `filename` like `abc.txt` but if there is any file with name `abc1.txt` the above method is giving `abc2.txt`. How to make the regex condition or change `(m.group(2) == null ? "_copy" + 1 : (Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)) + 1))` so that it returns me `abc1_copy1.txt` as new filename and not `abc2.txt` and so forth like `abc1_copy2` etc.

Comment: Just change - `(Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)) + 1))` to `(m.group(2) + "_copy" + 1)`

Comment: @RohitJain This will not work because it will keep on adding `_copy1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(_copy(\\d+))?(\\..*)?");

while(new File(fileName).exists())
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String prefix = m.group(1);
        String numberMatch = m.group(3);
        String suffix = m.group(4);
        int copyNumber = numberMatch == null ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(numberMatch) + 1;

        fileName = prefix;
        fileName += "_copy" + copyNumber;
        fileName += (suffix == null ? "" : suffix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a java guy, but in general, you should use libarary functions/classes for parsing filenames as many platforms have different rules for them.

Look at:
http://people.apache.org/~jochen/commons-io/site/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName(java.lang.String)